# Manage stream client server with Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I wonder how complex software client-server manage stream.
For example when I play counter strike, they are lots of packet send from client to server and server to clients. What is the best method to manage stream ?

I think :

**Server send data to client**

```c++
 void Server::send(const QString &message)
    {
        QByteArray paquet;
        QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

        out << (quint16) 0; //packet size
        out << (quint8)14; //packet type to execute a special action on the client
        out << message; // data, here string but can be another class
        out.device()->seek(0); 
        out << (quint16) (paquet.size() - sizeof(quint16)); //write packet size
        socket->write(paquet);        
    }
```

**Client receive data from server**

```c++
void Client::receiveData()
{
    QDataStream in(socket);

    if (size_packet == 0) // size_packet, initilize to 0
    {
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
             return;

        in >> tailleMessage;
    }    
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < tailleMessage)
        return;

    //now I can get data
    quint8 typeObject;
    in >> typeObject;



    switch(typeObject){
        case 1:
            ...
        break;

        case 2:
            ...
        break;

        case 3:
            ...
        break;

            ...
            ...

        case 14:
            QString data; //can be another custom class
            in >> data;
            write(data);
        break;

        //my solution, the server can execute an action on the client depending type packet
    }

    size_packet= 0;
}
```

I guess I have to use a shared library between the client and the server and serialized my custom class.

But should I do otherwise? Use json or xml or protocol buffer (google) or something else ???

Comment: Fast-paced online games generally use UDP for performance reasons.  There's a good article on this here: http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/

Answer (score 0):

As @MrEricSir mention, games usually use UDP protocol. It uses datagrams, not streams. So some datagrams can be lost during data transmission. You protocol should work with data lost. Often such protocol are binary, they do not use xml, json or protobuf because of overhead.